# ISTIO GRPC Gateway configuration

Tags: grpc, istio, gateway

I am trying to setup ISTIO Gateway with GRPC. I am using example from:https://github.com/h3poteto/istio-grpc-example.

This example does not contain Gateway. I added the Gateway:

```
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: istio-grpc-example
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: grpc-wildcard
      protocol: GRPC
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

and modified the VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: backend
  namespace: istio-grpc-example
spec:
  hosts:
    - "backend"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 50051
    route:
    - destination:
        host: backend
        subset: v0
      weight: 90
    - destination:
        host: backend
        subset: v1
      weight: 10
```

Is there somethig else I should do? I still cannot go through Gateway… Received an error when querying services endpoint.

Thank you!

Comment: @please show your error, I see that you are using subsets, did you define destination rules?

Comment: They didn´t use gateway in this example, so did you try if it works with default gateway? As @c4f4t0r mentioned could you show your errors? Have you tried with wildcard hosts?  ¨*¨ instead of ¨backend¨.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. I changed the port number from 80 to 31400 and changed the host from "backend" to "*". Now it looks like everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments

> Have you tried with wildcard hosts? `*` instead of `backend`?

You need to change virtual service [hosts](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/).

```
spec:
  hosts:
    - "backend"
```

**to**

```
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
```

And @Ondra add that other thing he changed was the gateway [port number](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/#Port).

> I changed the port number from 80 to 31400 and changed the host from "backend" to "*". Now it looks like everything is working. – Ondra